# Laptop does not wake up from deep sleep

Tags: suspend, lenovo

I'm using a Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6 laptop. Currently running ZorinOS 17, but I also have the exact same issue on Ubuntu 22.04. Kernel version is 6.8 but it's the same on 5.15 and any other version I tried.

By running the command 'cat /sys/power/mem_sleep', I can see that it uses 'deep' sleep.

I'd like to upload the log file found at /var/log/syslog but it's too big. How can I filter what's needed for troubleshooting the problem?

**Update: fixed by installing Liquorix kernel 6.7.1**

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Zorin forum.  (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Zorin so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Answer (score -1):

I am running a Toshiba Sat Pro which had the same problem...i cured it by entering the bios at boot and disabling the LAN at boot up....now it comes out of suspend everytime

Comment: I fixed it by installing Liquorix kernel (6.7.1 - 1).

Comment: How did you come to that change?  The process of finding out how to solve a problem is often interesting.